# Can I use Neo4j BI Connector with my Java app?

Tags: java, neo4j

Neo4j have recently added a BI connector tool (neo4j.com/bi-connector) which can return relational data from your graph database to your business intelligence tool such as Tableau. The question is can i send SQL queries to this connector assuming i have added the jar file to my java application class path? If yes, which APIs should i use to send this SQL query to the driver?
I'm using Neo4j4.0.

Comment: Could you share the tool? It sounds like it's an executable so theoretically could execute it and pull the output from stdout or something but it sounds like using https://neo4j.com/developer/java/ would be a much better fit.

Comment: https://neo4j.com/bi-connector/
bi connector enables you to send SQL queries to a graph and get the results back in tabular form. The driver doesn't.

Comment: I see, I think i understand better after looking at the tool. If you look at the document PDF that you get when you download it, on page 10 where they show how to establish a connection. After you have that, you have a standard JDBC connection which is a Java interface that tells libraries how to talk to a sql database. There are a lot of different tools that use this interface, it's kind of user preference. A common one is JOOQ https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/getting-started/tutorials/jooq-in-7-steps/. Let me know if that works and I'll post this as an answer if so :)

Comment: I got it. Please post this as answer and i'll mark it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For neo4j.com/bi-connector, if you look at the document PDF that you get when you download it, on page 10 where they show how to establish a connection you'll see that you get a [connection object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html). After you have that, you have a standard JDBC connection which is a Java interface that tells libraries how to talk to a SQL database. There are a lot of different tools that use this interface, it's kind of user preference. A common one is [JOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/getting-started/tutorials/jooq-in-7-steps/).